# Wordpress get post field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am overriding the admin email notification template in WooCommerce and when the order transaction is successful I want to add the transaction id in the email.

I tried `$order->get_transaction_id()` [as explained here](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderget_transaction_id/) in the admin email template, but it returns an empty result.

I then tried this in the admin email template:

```
do_action('getOrderTransactionID', $order->id);
```

And in my theme's functions.php I added this but this function doesn't return anything either.

```
add_action('getOrderTransactionID', 'getOrderTransactionIDForEmail');

function getOrderTransactionIDForEmail($orderId){
    echo get_metadata('post', $orderId, '_transaction_id', true);

    //get_post_data doesn't return anything either
    //get_post_meta( $orderId, '_transaction_id', true);
}
```

In the `wp_postmeta` table, the `_transaction_id` meta key is saved after each successful transaction. Why then am I unable to retrieve the `_transaction_id` which is already in the database?

Comment: Is order saved with the type of 'post' or it has some other type?

Comment: In the `wp_post` table I see the `post_type` for the order record is `shop_order`

Comment: The first parameter to `get_metadata` is the object type (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata). Surely Woocommerce's orders don't use the default WordPress `post` type?

Comment: So that is the problem you're trying to get metadata of type `post` but you have `shop_order`

Comment: try using `echo get_metadata('shop_order', $orderId, '_transaction_id', true);`

Comment: I just changed  `get_metadata('post'.....)` to `get_metadata('shop_order'....)` but did't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gateway are you using? If you don't see `_transaction_id` then you need to save the returned transaction_id manually in your gateway plugin. [Check out this page](http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/08/wc-2-2-payment-gateways-adding-refund-support-and-transaction-ids/)

Try saving transaction id in your payment gateway file, then try to see if it displays when you do `var_dump(get_post_custom($order->id));`

```
add_post_meta( $order->id, '_transaction_id', YOUR_TRANSACTION_ID, true );
```

Comment: What's good about this is that I don't have to any `woocommerce_email_order_meta` or add anything in my theme's functions. `$order->get_transaction_id()` method in my admin email template returns the transaction id now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how to add data to email templates using existing hooks.

```
function kia_display_email_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $some_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ),
    $another_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ),
    if( $plain_text ){
        echo 'The value for some field is ' . $some_field . ' while the value of another field is ' . $another_field;
    } else {
        echo '<p>The value for <strong>some field</strong> is ' . $some_field. ' while the value of <strong>another field</strong> is ' . $another_field;</p>;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'kia_display_email_order_meta', 30, 3 );
```

Comment: What is `30` and `3`?

Comment: This didn't really help me.  `get_post_meta` doesn't return any value for me.

Comment: This is a sample. Unless you have `_some_field` and `_another_field` as meta values, then you won't be returning anything. You need to modify with your desired meta keys... which I believe is `_transaction_id`.

Comment: `30` and `3` are priority and number of variables to pass from action hook.  See [`add_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Comment: I added your code in my theme's functions and of course changed it to `_transaction_id` and called `do_action('kia_display_email_order_meta', $order)` in the admin email template. Still nothing happening. Doesn't return anything.

Comment: Assuming your template has the `woocommerce_email_order_meta` hook, you don't need to add any new `do_action` hooks. That's the point of my 'add_action' line. Try disabling your theme's custom template (thereby reverting to the WC default). I have already tested this code for [my tutorial](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/?p=517) so I'm 98% sure it works.

Comment: Appreciate the comments. The function still doesn't return the `_transaction_id`. I added `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text );` in the admin email template just like the original WC one. I made sure the function receives the `$order`, I am able to display order id in the email returning from `kia_display_email_order_meta` method in the functions.php, but not the transaction id which returns nothing.

Comment: `echo get_post_meta( $order->id, '_transaction_id', true );` defined inside `kia_display_email_order_meta($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text)` method returns nothing.

Comment: I can only assume that you do not have anything stored for that meta. :/ What do you get if you `var_dump(get_post_custom($order->id));` ?

Comment: Lots of things except `_transaction_id`. But `_transaction_id` meta_value is not empty.

Comment: If it isn't in `get_post_custom()` then it isn't in the meta for that order